# Yii2: How to renderPartial with Bootstrap classes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, controller, yii2, html.renderpartial

I am trying to use **renderPartial** function and **Bootstrap** classes.

**This is my function in the controller file:**

```
public function actionPrintReport() {
    Yii::$app->response->format = 'pdf';
    return $this->renderPartial('_myReport', []);
}
```

**This is my _myReport file that is rendered:** My own styles works but not the Bootstrap classes.

```
<div class="box box-warning">
    <div class="box-body">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

But the result doesn't show any Bootstrap class:

[image: Rendered result]

I also tried **renderAjax** but the same result.

Comment: have you check if the bootstrap css are correctly loaded?

Comment: I don't know how to check it. Bootstrap classes works in renders views but not in renderPartial views.

Comment: I suppose .box-body class has a css rules so you have to check with browser inspector what happen.

Comment: I just checked but the Bootstrap classes are not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is much the point with the function [renderPartial()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#renderPartial()-detail)

> Renders a view without applying layout.
>
> This method differs from render() in that it does not apply any layout.

The renderPartial function is often used when you'll render the same block of code several times in one page. What was your expected result here? What are you trying to do?

registerAssets is usually loaded in the main view file (the one that is not not rendered). You should have a look at the main layout file and understand how assets are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

```
Asset::register($this);
```

in your view `_myReports`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same as you, I got the solution.

You just needed to check the struture of main file:

1. In you "_..." file, add HTML

```
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>" class="h-100">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <?php $this->registerCsrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

<div class="container-xl outlined-box p-2 m-1 ">
    <div class="row  ">
    test
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary ">asdasd</a>
</div>

<h1>asdasdasd</h1>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>

<?php $this->endPage();
```

2. Don't forget to put this in the top of your PHP file (after imports btw)

```
    frontend\assets\AppAsset::register($this);
```